# Asterisk cli console is displaying a resolve socket address error that i need help solving

Tags: syntax, asterisk, sip

how do i solve the following error:

netsock2.c:269 ast_sockaddr_resolve: getaddrinfo("1rtywEer", "46455", ...): Name or service not known

cannot seem to find many references to it on google, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the end user sending a malformed sip packet.